# How to Configure AWS Glue SQL Query Transform to TRUNCATE then Load Target DB Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need this accomplished by using the Glue Visual ETL editor, and not PySpark or Scala.

In diagram 1, I have a SQL Server RDS target defined in the Glue Catalog and configured as parent node for the SQL query transform.

image1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY4mw.png)

Diagram 2 below shows my SQL query transform configuration.

image2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q30i8.png)

And I'm getting "table not found" error message although the table is defined in the data catalog.

image3 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cxp8.png)

Thank you for your help.

I configured the glue data catalog and sql query transform,but is getting a table not found error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where do you want to truncate the table. Is it in source or target?
2. Whatever truncate you used in the images it is spark sql it wont do anything for either source or target.
3. If you want to truncate and insert into table in target you can use your target block and add your preaction command or use truncate and insert option.
4. If you want to just truncate the table in source go for different option that is supported by source.